# document.getElementById() is always returning null

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I'm trying to get the value of a hidden input from a form in my HTML, using javascript.
But after trying several different ways to get the value, it always says in console(firebug) that the variable is null.. heres the javascript:

```
var mcq_test = form.mcq_test.value;
console.log("mcqid=" + mcq_test)
var mcq_num_questions = form.mcq_num_questions.value;
console.log("totalquestions=" + mcq_num_questions)
var x = 1;
var send = [];
send.push("mcq_test=");
send.push(mcq_test);

console.log("Send: " + send);

// have commented out the bits below...just go through them carefully looking at the string functions, put them in the send += (SRING 1 + STRING 2 + ...) format

for (var x = 1; x <= mcq_num_questions; x++) {
var questionidd = "mcq_question_id";
console.log("1 = " + questionidd);
var questionid = questionidd.concat(x); // mcq_question_id$ctr the question numer
console.log("2 = " + questionid);
var mcqid = form.questionid.value; // the questions id on db
console.log("3 = " + mcqid);
var answerr = "mcq_question";
var answer = answerr.concat(x); // mcq_question$ctr the questions chosen answer
var chosenanswer = form.answer.value; // the answers value
console.log("4 = " + chosenanswer);
var amp = "&";
var equal = "=";
var questionide = questionid.concat(equal); // "mcq_question_id$ctr="
var questionida = amp.concat(questionide); // "&mcq_question_id$ctr="
var answere = amp.concat(answer,equal); // "&mcq_question$ctr="
if (x = 1) { send.push(questionide, mcqid, answere, chosenanswer); }
else {
send.push(questionida, mcqid, answere, chosenanswer);
}
}
```

Console:

```
[04:08:00.328] TypeError: questionID is null 
[04:08:00.327] My new function
[04:08:00.327] mcqid=566
[04:08:00.327] totalquestions=3
[04:08:00.327] Send: mcq_test=,566
[04:08:00.328] 1 = mcq_question_id
[04:08:00.328] 2 = mcq_question_id1
```

Form:

```
echo"<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"mcq_question_id$ctr\" id=\"mcq_question_id$ctr\" value=\"$questionID\" form=\"SubmitTest\" />";
```

-- Update

Answer found! Turns out, you can't use the syntax document.getElementByID() or form.variable.value; and put a variable in there, it has to be a string or written like this:

```
form[variable].value;
```

I didn't find an equivalent for getElementById but the form method works for me.

Comment: tell me how many questions id in your page and post your whole code

Comment: On this page, 3, but it's variable depending on which test you go on - we have tests with up to 100 questions, would you like me to post the whole javascript part or include the html too?

Comment: bit more infor now if that help @ManishNagar

Comment: from which value you start your $ctr when you are creating input type id for questions

Comment: remove 'var' from  for (var x = 1; x <= mcq_num_questions; x++)  because 'x' is already declare

Comment: Where in your code are you calling document.getElementById()? It's the subject of your question yet not present in your code. Where is questionID? Don't see that either.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the DOM has loaded before you try accessing it. Put the Javascript after the HTML or setup an event to trigger the variable definition.

Comment: The event is triggered by a button, is that enough or is there something else I need to add?

Comment: Then ensure before you click the button, the element is already there.

Comment: That should be enough... what's in `$ctr`?

Comment: I mentioned briefly in the question, its a number start at 1 and increments by 1 each loop, for each question on the page - giving every input a different id, e.g. mcq_question_id2

Comment: @luiges90 I'm not quite sure what you mean, the element is definitely on the page, and I wait for the page to load before trying

Comment: When viewing the source of the page, can you CTRL+F and find an element with an id of "mcq_question_id1"?

Comment: yup found this <input type="hidden" name="mcq_question_id1" id="mcq_question_id1" value="8068" form="SubmitTest" /> and one for each of the questions on the page

Comment: yeh, here http://www.mycqs.com/mcqs/Computer+Science/Information+Technology/A-Z+Unix/?mcq_src=5 scroll to the bottom, the first 'mark' button works, but i'm trying to make the test mark through ajax, using this second button

Comment: @OmairVaiyani - I'm unable to recreate the error you're reporting

Answer (score 0):

when using this

```
echo"<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"mcq_question_id$ctr\" id=\"mcq_question_id$ctr\" value=\"$questionID\" form=\"SubmitTest\" />";
```

here before going to create input type make sure your '$questionID' is not null

use this then test

```
echo"<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"mcq_question_id$ctr\" id=\"mcq_question_id$ctr\" value=\"questions\" form=\"SubmitTest\" />";
```

Comment: The code I showed was part of a longer function, if I used this function, will I be able to place it within my other function? - and yes the input types start from mcq_question_id1

Comment: $questionID is not null - and it can't be null because the question wouldn't show up without it