# HTMLElements are not found by .getElementById() if commented out - is this normal behavior?

Tags: javascript, html

I was trying to see what type the `.hasAttribute()` method returned. I had the following code:

```
HTML:
<!--
<img id="theimg" src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
-->

JS:
var myimg = document.getElementById("theimg");
var result = myimg.hasAttribute('src');
console.log(typeof result);
```

My console kept throwing this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasAttribute' of null`

Interestingly, once I un-commented the HTML, `myimg` was no longer null, and `.hasAttribute('src');` gleefully returned a boolean.

Since `.getElementById()` does not appear to locate commented out HTMLElements, **how does one retrieve commented out HTMLElements?**

I have tried:

1. Massaging the code to see if I could force `.getElementById()` to work, e.g. by trying `console.log(document.getElementById("theimg").src);`
2. Googling
3. Reading [the MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById) on `.getElementById()`, which simply says

> "If there is no element with the given id, this function returns
>   `null`...Elements not in the document are not searched by
>   getElementById."

But surely the commented out text is part of the document!

Searching SO I found [this question about accessing a hidden form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14078655/document-getelementbyid-is-always-returning-null) but it did not answer my question.

Comment: comments are in fact part of the DOM, the nodeType is 8, and they can be accessed, but is that really what you're asking? Of course, regular DOM methods doesn't work on elements that are commented out, as that would defeat the entire purpose of comments !

Comment: You know i never thought about it like that but what you said makes sense! I was just curious and exploring while I learn ^_^ - And yes, that was my real question, how do you access comment nodes (see the boldface line in my question...)

Comment: You can retrieve the comment DOM node itself, but you cannot retrieve the elements inside the comment since they are not part of the DOM. They are not parsed as markup at all. You shouldn't use a comment if you just want to hide elements but still wants to be able to access them.

Answer (score 3):

yes, this is normal. As ridiculous as your question is, it merits a real answer: anything you comment off gets inserted into the DOM as a comment node, and does not count as markup. A comment is **nothing** like a hidden form element: the first is not a DOM node, but annotation data. The second is a real DOM node, and if you applied CSS to it such as `display: block` it would show up on the page like anything else.

And I called this question ridiculous, because it's one of the most basic rules of HTML markup. HTML does stuff, if you comment it off, it does nothing and as far as anyone is concerned, doesn't exist except when you view the source.

Answer (score -1):

you have an error in your `console.log()` method

you should concatenate the string simply add a + between the string and the variable.

i tested it like this and it worked

```
<img id="theimg" src="http://placehold.it/100x100"> 
<script type="text/javascript">
var myimg = document.getElementById("theimg");
var result = myimg.hasAttribute('src');
console.log("type is "+ result);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this is incorrect. `typeof` is not a string in my code, it's an operator that returns the type of the variable coming afterwards - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Comment: oh yah that's true i found this code works like a charm                    
`<img id="theimg" src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
<script type="text/javascript">
var myimg = document.getElementById("theimg");
var result = myimg.hasAttribute('src');
var type = typeof result;
console.log(type);
</script>`                                                                     i tried it myself and in the console it gave me the type which was booleon